# Rewrite .htaccess buffling issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp

So I'm trying to rewrite some urls for a website I'm working on. The rewrite files read as:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /NetbeansProjects/App/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/+$ $1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/*$ index.php?page=index [NC]
RewriteRule ^([webapp/]+)/([main/]+)/?$ /NetbeansProjects/App/index.php?page=$1_$2  [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([webapp/]+)/([dashboard/]+)/?$ /NetbeansProjects/App/index.php?page=$1_$2  [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([webapp/]+)/([search/]+)/?$ /NetbeansProjects/App/index.php?page=$1_$2  [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([search/]+)/?$ /NetbeansProjects/App/index.php?page=college_$1  [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([webapp/]+)/([apply/]+)/?$ /NetbeansProjects/App/index.php?page=$1_$2  [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([webapp/]+)/(.*)/([main/]+)/?$ /NetbeansProjects/App/index.php?page=$1_$3&uni=$2  [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([webapp/]+)/(.*)/([apply/]+)/?$ /NetbeansProjects/App/index.php?page=$1_$3&uni=$2  [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([webapp/]+)/(.*)/?$ /NetbeansProjects/App/index.php?page=index [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^about/?$ index.php?page=about [NC]
RewriteRule ^webapp/?$ index.php?page=college_no_login [NC]
RewriteRule ^faq/?$ index.php?page=faq [NC]
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ index.php?page=contact [NC]
RewriteRule ^planner/?$ index.php?page=planner [NC]
```

The main issue is when I pass my url as:

```
http://www.example.com/webapp/dash or http://www.example.com/webapp/sos
```

For some reason it redirects wrongly. The localserver is passing this line as true:

```
RewriteRule ^([webapp/]+)/([dashboard/]+)/?$ /NetbeansProjects/App/index.php?page=$1_$2  [NC,QSA]
```

Which should not be the case. I was able to detect that using this website: http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/

UPDATE: This code seems to be working as desired for now

```
RewriteRule ^(webapp+)/(dashboard+)/?$ /NetbeansProjects/App/index.php?page=$1_$2 [NC,QSA]
```

on each line I removed `'[', ']'`

Comment: You don't need `+` after `webapp` and `dashboard`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mistake in your regexes. The `[abc]` expression stands for one of a set of characters.

This means that `[dashboard/]` matches any of "d", "a", "s", etc. so `[dashboard/]+` matches any string that consist of any number of "d", "a", "s", etc. but at least one of them altogether.

You need to remove the `[]`. For grouping, use `()` - however I believe you don't need it in this case:

```
(foo/)+
```

Same for `[webapp/]`, so the rule becomes:

```
RewriteRule ^(webapp/)/(dashboard/)/?$ /NetbeansProjects/App/index.php?page=$1_$2  [NC,QSA]
```

Comment: I get what you're trying to say but your solution didn't work it. It gave me an Error 404

Comment: I believe this is the rule you were proposing: `RewriteRule ^(webapp+)/(dashboard+)/?$ /NetbeansProjects/App/index.php?page=$1_$2  [NC,QSA]`

Comment: Surely not. That would match `.../dashboardddd/`. I'm guessing that's not desired. However it's not clear what you exactly expect. What's in the error log? What file the web server actually trying to access?

Comment: i cross checked and that didn't match `.../dashboardddd/`. It gave an Error 404 there.